# Previsualizar un tema, modificarlo y guardar los cambios

Tags: wordpress

Verán, quiero cambiar el tema de mi página web.
Para ello, me he decantado por Catch Box, en el cual me he ido al modo de pre-visualización.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El caso es que he hecho en ese modo algunas modificaciones y ahora quiero que se guarde un borrador.
No quiero aún activar el nuevo tema, pero tampoco quiero que al salir del modo de pre-visualización se pierda los cambios realizados.

Comment: No te parece mas facil/seguro hacer una copia en local/otro host y hacer las modificaciones que quieras e ir probando los nuevos cambios?

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es un theme child, desde allí puedes hacer los cambios que quieras y probar los cambios en el host local, guardarlos y cuando quieras activar el nuevo tema subir el theme child.

Comment: Ya escuche sobre la opción de hacer una copia de seguridad para poder alegremente modificar el tema de la página y poder regresar como estaba antes de hacer falta. El problema es que no se como hago eso, pues como mucho he encontrado como pasar a ZIP los artículos y entradas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione. Resulta que si activo un momentito el nuevo tema y luego rápidamente vuelvo al original, se guardaran los cambios.
Con esto este problema esta solucionado.